# How can i make my caroutine run in every x seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a caroutine, and i want it to run in every x seconds. i tried using while loop but it didn't worked for this caroutine. can anybody please help ? thanks.

```
 IEnumerator StartFire()
{

   
    {
        Firing = true;

        animator.SetBool("isFiring", true);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

        Firing = false;

        animator.SetBool("isFiring", false);

    }


}
```

Comment: Put a while loop in there and wait at the end for however long you want it to be between cycles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be better off using `InvokeRepeating(string methodName, float time, float repeatRate)`. You only need to call it once and it will repeat.

Example:

```
void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("myTask", 1.5f, 1.5f);
}

void myTask()
{
    // Execute repetitive task.
}
```

If you want to stop it at any point you simply have to call: `CancelInvoke(string methodName);`.

Example:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        CancelInvoke();
}
```

This would put an end to the repetitive task.